# constraint that limits number of children in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a databased which looks like

```
Root
    Child Table 1
        Child table referencing 1
    Child Table 2
    Child Table 3
    Child Table N
         Child Table referencing N
```

One of the requirements given to me is to limit the number of children for each row in root.

There can only be 4 child1 rows per root row.

There can only be 12 child2 rows per root row.

etc.

I know that I can build a set of checks into the business logic of my program but I was wondering if there is a way to include a set of constraints at the database that would do the sanity checks for me? [None of the foreign key reference options seem to do what I want](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: I understand that you want to restrict row values depending on values in other rows (which is a good question). But your "root table" diagram is very confusing IMHO.

Comment: I'm trying to not give away company names. =P
I'll try to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you will have to do this with triggers since MySQL does not honor check constraints. That trigger will need to query for the count of rows for the given foreign key value and if that exceeds your count, to throw an error. So, something akin to:

```
Create Trigger TrigChildTable
    Before Insert
    On ChildTable 
    For Each Row
Begin

If Exists   (
            Select 1
            From ChildTable
            Where ParentFKColumn = New.ParentFKColumn
            Having Count(*) > 3 -- Max count - 1
            )
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot have more than 4 child rows for a given parent';

End
```

If MySQL honored check constraints (which it doesn't), you could do something like:

```
-- add a sequence or counter column
Alter Table ChildTable
    Add Sequence int not null;

-- add a unique constraint/index on the foreign key column + sequence
Alter Table ChildTable
    Add Constraint UC_Parent_Sequence 
        Unique ( ParentFKColumn, Sequence )

-- using a check constraint, require that the sequence value
-- be between 0 and 4
Alter Table ChildTable
    Add Constraint CK_Sequence Check ( Sequence Between 0 And 4 )
```

Comment: which databases honor check constraints?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins - Most actually. Microsoft SQL Server (all versions), Oracle, DB2, Postgres, Informix, Sybase, SQLite (after 3.3.0)...